# Is there a ChildWindow equivalent on Windows Phone 7? How to do rich modal popups

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a phone app and need a modal dialog with some "rich" content - a few text boxes and a drop down.  OK, not very rich but more than a MessageBox. :>

In regular Silverlight I know there's the ChildWindow control - but can't find the equivalent in Phone 7.

How have other folks done rich popup dialogs on the phone?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Will, how does popup work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight actually has a control called a Popup. [Here's the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(VS.95).aspx).

It's incredibly simple to use (just set IsOpen to true to dispay) and quite effective. The only reason you might use a Panel with manual state control would be is you want precision control over animations etc.

Comment: Perfect.  I was looking for ChildWindow, didn't realize there was a Popup class

Answer (score 1):

Where I've seen people implement something like this they just have added a panel to the page and made this visible to act as a modal popup.
If you do this, be sure to handle use of the back button correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is ChildWindow on Windows Phone 7 in `System.Windows.Controls` library.

These are some examples:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-implement-childwindow-in-windows-phone-7/

http://blog.deepwire.co.uk/?p=434

http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2011/06/how-to-create-childwindow-login-popup.html